# in Android MVVM, how many repositories and networking clients that I need to make to serve different queries?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

I am new in using MVVM and Android architecture, and I am little bit confused.

say for example I want to make an app like Youtube, as you know youtube has these tabs in their bottom navigation: Home, subscription, Trending(explore)

those 3 tabs will show recylerview of items (video object), those 3 will show data from 3 different queries.

in MVVM using viewmodel and livedata, the data stream will be like this

fragment <-- viewModel <-- repository <-- client

so for those 3 tabs I will have 3 different fragments, and it also mean I will have 3 different viewModels. now I am not sure how many repositories and networking clients do I need to have

am I right if I only have 1 repository and 1 networking client ? how many repositories and clients do I need to have ?

each viewModel will retrieve liveData from this `VideoRepository` below code below, and eventually each fragment will observe data from each viewModel

```
object VideoRepository {

    val homeVideos: LiveData<List<Video>> = VideoRetrofitClient.homeVideos
    val subscriptionVideos: LiveData<List<Video>> = VideoRetrofitClient.subscriptionVideos
    val trendingVideos: LiveData<List<Video>> = VideoRetrofitClient.trendingVideos

    fun searchHomeVideos() {
        VideoRetrofitClient.searchHomeVideos()
    }

    fun searchSubscriptionVideos() {
        VideoRetrofitClient.searchHomeVideos()
    }

    fun searchTrendingVideos() {
        VideoRetrofitClient.searchHomeVideos()
    }

}
```

and `VideoRepository` will get LiveData from this `VideoRetrofitClient` like this code

```
object VideoRetrofitClient {
    val homeVideos = MutableLiveData<List<Video>>()
    val subscriptionVideos = MutableLiveData<List<Video>>()
    val trendingVideos = MutableLiveData<List<Video>>()


    fun searchHomeVideos() {
        // perform networking ....

        homeVideos.postValue(videos)
    }

    fun searchSubscriptionVideos() {
        // perform networking ....

        subscriptionVideos.postValue(videos)
    }

    fun searchTrendingVideos() {
        // perform networking ....

        trendingVideos.postValue(videos)
    }
}
```

java or kotlin are ok

Answer (score 1):

You need one repository for each model (data).

Video model has a VideoRepository interface.

Your repositories could be one of below:

- `InMemoryRepository`
- `DatabaseRepository`
- `RemoteRepository`

When working with MVVM think about the model (data) first.

1. I have some data (videos) to save, so I need a model for that.
2. I need to save read/write that model so I need a repository.
3. My repository needs to save/read from database so I need `VideoDatabaseRepostory`

```
interface VideoRepository {
  fun getVideos(type: VideoType)
  fun getVideo(videoId: Int)
  fun uploadVideo(file: File)
}
```

```
class VideoDatabaseRepository : VideoRepository {

    // Accepts an enum to decide which API to call.
    fun getVideos(type: VideoType) {
        when (type) {
            FavoriteVideos -> {   }
            RecentVideos -> { }
            ...  
        }
    }

}
```

In network mode, you need some web API that filters results based on your query to the API.

Comment: the actual query actually on the backend, so I just get the restful API from the backend. so my client code just receive video data from bakcend. in that case, is it ok (common practice) to have 3 LiveData properties in one repository like my code above ?

Comment: if I see the diagram from Android here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/images/final-architecture.png, it seems that repository is a hub to decide whether to get data from Room Database or from server (retrofit) . so I am confused when you said  "your repositories could be one of below: InMemoryRepository, DatabaseRepository, RemoteRepository"

Comment: @Alexa289 I updated my code so you can use an enum to decide and redirect retrofit call based on that. if it helped please don't forget to check and + the answer.

Comment: I am sorry, I am a beginner, I don't really understand your solution, so how many LiveData that I need to store in my Repository ? 3 different videos livedata like my repository ?

Comment: I have 3 kind of video, home video, trending video, and subscription video. do I only need 1 live data to transfer list of videos to fragment/activity in my one repository ? or do I need to make 3 live data in my one repository ?

Comment: @Alexa289You can use one LiveData with 3 Transformations to map them in seperate observers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your query you can distingues them by passing parameter which can be enum type. then you can call only one repository method by just passing different type in a parameter. If it's no possible then you have to create three different queries for repository also in client.

Comment: the actual query actually on the backend, so I just get the restful API from the backend. so my client code just receive video data from bakcend. in that case, is it ok (common practice) to have 3 LiveData properties in one repository like my code above ?

Comment: As stated here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata?hl=fr you shouldn't hold LiveData in repositories